# How does a JavaScript engine choose what to execute next?

Tags: javascript

While I am syntactically proficient at JavaScript, I am clueless as to what goes on under the hood. Especially as to what is actually running when and how the JavaScript engine schedules it, if indeed it's scheduled in any sense of the word. I am so clueless that I don't even know what terminology I should use to research it.

I have always just assumed, from simply hearing others parrot it, that JavaScript engines can only run one thread at a time. Assuming that is true and a function is running when a callback occurs, what happens behind the scenes?
Is the currently running function paused and the callback executed or is the full stack of the currently running function unwound, then the code in the callback is run.

I am just clueless and it is shameful...

How does all this fit in with the UI thread in the browser, how is it different in node.js

Sorry if this question is a bit open ended, in the end what I am really asking boils down to -- What should I research(i.e Google) to learn more about all of this.

Comment: Read [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS), it covers the basic internal workings of Javascript rather well. Also, ever since web-workers came around, Javascript is no longer single-threaded.

Comment: JavaScript has an event loop. What happens behind the scenes is that when an event occurs (e.g. a timeout, user event, server-sent event etc.) that event is put into a queue of events. When the current function completes execution then the next event on the queue is processed. Until then all the events in the queue wait. If there are no more events to be processed then the event loop remains idle until another event comes. It's kind of like when you're standing in line at a bank waiting for the teller to service you. There's only one teller (single threaded) and it's first come first serve. =)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Answer (score 0):

The function currently being executed finishes its execution before the callback is run. This can be implemented in different ways by different engines.

Node is not different and the engine responsible for executing JavaScript code is shared with browsers.

Since you can't run two or more functions at the same time, and one function needs to finish its execution before the other gets to be executed, JavaScript is said to be single threaded.

Web workers run on a separate environment, so their execution is not dependent on the code running in the page or other web workers.